# pyclustering using CCORE implementation

Tags: python, cluster-computing

On the website [pyclustering](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyclustering) the author mention that:

> There is ability to use python code implementation only or CCORE
>   (C/C++) implementation using special flag.

But there is not any example how to use the special flag. 
Has anyone an idea how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

In line with [github page of the library](https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering), argument 'ccore_flag' should be True for particular algorithm instance that is going to be used:

```
# read input data
input_data = read_sample(FCPS_SAMPLES.SAMPLE_LSUN);

# use ccore_flag parameter to use ccore.so (or ccore.dll) in case of CURE algorithm.
cure_instance = cure(input_data, 3, ccore_flag= True);

# use ccore_flag for DBSCAN algorithm (the last argument).
dbscan_instance = dbscan(input_data, 0.5, 3, True);
```

Comment: annoviko, you are the author, right?  I am running on mac, ccore enabled, and I get an attribute error: dlsym(RTLD_DEFAULT, xmeans_algorithm): symbol not found when running xmeans on some dummy data with ccore enabled.  Do you want me to post a question on here, or is there a pyclustering forum to use?

Comment: I am sorry, but the core of pyclustering does not support MAC OS, only Windows and Unix (Linux). In case of MAC OS core should be disabled. Otherwise you can try to build the core manually. There is description how to do that on Linux: https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering/wiki/Installing . Anyway, you can open issue on gihub page of the library (https://github.com/annoviko/pyclustering/issues) and I will try to help you to build it for MAC step by step.

Comment: thanks man--I think I've gotten it working on the cluster.  following your instructions from the wiki for building the ccore

Comment: You are welcome, do not hesitate to ask any question related to pyclustering. I will try to support MAC for the core using Travis-CI, they provide feature to test builds on MAC OS, but it's much better to have at hand real platform to be able to handle any problem ASAP.

Comment: Awesome; thank you!  We'll be using this with some pretty good sized datasets on a routine basis; both the core and Python shell are the major decision points.  I'll definitely let you know if we run into questions/issues